# Loading svg on a fabric js canvas doesn't display circle shapes

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js to load an SVG on the canvas. The SVG element is a table displaying various canvas info.
The table contains multiple elements out of which circle and line elements.

My issue is that lines display correctly, circles however don't display at all.

Though it may not be relevant, these elements are generated by drawing on a temporary canvas and then exporting it as an SVG.

When loading the svg I use the good old fabric.loadSVGFromString, blow is an example of how laoding svg on canvas is performed:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(options.svgLegend, function (results, renderOptions) {
      var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(results, renderOptions);                
      annotationManager.canvas.add(obj);
      annotationManager.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

After

Below is an example of the generated SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
<title>Legend</title>
<g x="0" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="18px" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="start">
    <text x="0" dy="1em">Style</text>
    <text id="sortLegendEstimator" x="175" dy="1em">Author</text>
    <text id="sortLegendType" x="350" dy="1em">Type</text>
    <text id="sortLegendQuantity" x="525" dy="1em">Quantity</text>
    <text id="sortLegendDescription" x="700" dy="1em">Description</text>
</g>
<g x="0" y="20" font-size="18px" text-anchor="start">
    <svg>
        <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="10" cy="40" r="25" strokeWidth="4" stroke="#ff887c" fill="#000000" />
    </svg>
    <svg>
        <line xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="40" y="40" strokeWidth="4" stroke="#ff887c" strokeDashArray="undefined" />
    </svg>
    <text x="175" dy="1.5em">xxxxxxx</text>
    <text x="350" dy="1.5em">connected line</text>
    <text x="525" dy="1.5em">266.28 ft</text>
    <g x="700" dy="1.5em">
        <text x="700" y="20" text-anchor="start">Babilonia, și în special capitala sa, orașul Babilon, au fost pentru mult timp u</text>
    </g>
</g>
<g x="0" y="50" font-size="18px" text-anchor="start">
    <svg>
        <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="10" cy="70" r="25" strokeWidth="4" stroke="#ff887c" fill="#000000" />
    </svg>
    <text x="175" dy="1.5em">xxxxxxx</text>
    <text x="350" dy="1.5em">point group</text>
    <text x="525" dy="1.5em">3</text>
</g>
<g x="0" y="80" font-size="18px" text-anchor="start">
    <svg>
        <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="10" cy="100" r="25" strokeWidth="4" stroke="#ff887c" fill="#000000" />
    </svg>
    <svg>
        <line xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="40" y="100" strokeWidth="4" stroke="#ff887c" strokeDashArray="undefined" />
    </svg>
    <text x="175" dy="1.5em">xxxxxxx</text>
    <text x="350" dy="1.5em">connected line</text>
    <text x="525" dy="1.5em">67.03 ft</text>
</g>
<g x="0" y="110" font-size="18px" text-anchor="start">
    <svg>
        <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="10" cy="130" r="25" strokeWidth="12" stroke="#dc2127" fill="#000000" />
    </svg>
    <svg>
        <line xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="40" y="130" strokeWidth="12" stroke="#dc2127" strokeDashArray="undefined" />
    </svg>
    <text x="175" dy="1.5em">xxxxxxx</text>
    <text x="350" dy="1.5em">connected line</text>
    <text x="525" dy="1.5em">87.53 ft</text>
</g>
<g x="0" y="140" font-size="18px" text-anchor="start">
    <svg>
        <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="10" cy="160" r="25" strokeWidth="4" stroke="#ff887c" fill="#000000" />
    </svg>
    <svg>
        <line xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="40" y="160" strokeWidth="4" stroke="#ff887c" strokeDashArray="undefined" />
    </svg>
    <text x="175" dy="1.5em">xxxxxxx</text>
    <text x="350" dy="1.5em">connected line</text>
    <text x="525" dy="1.5em">97.2 ft</text>
</g>
```

By now I've tried almost everything except. Dropping off the SVG is not a choice since it lets fabric handle much of the functionality needed for it ( dragging, resizing, etc.. ), the svg is basically a table legend. Any sort of help is welcomed.

Comment: This is strange since your lines are not correctly defined. What I can't see are the lines.

Comment: wonderful, fabric was setting the width to 0 for ellipses and circles, this solved itself out :/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

The issue was that fabric was loading the svg shapes with a 0 width by default. Solved this by explicitly setting circle's width to their radius as below:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(options.svgLegend, function (results, renderOptions) {

            results.filter(function(obj){ if(obj.type === 'circle'){ obj.width = obj.radius; } });
```

NOTE: I did notice lines weren't constructed right ( with x and y coordinates instead of x1, x2, y1, y2 ), but that was not the cause of my issue.